# Why does Cython create all these temporary variables? And is it wise/possible to avoid?

Tags: variables, optimization, cython

When you annotate code in Cython you notice that it create a lot of temporary __pyx_t variables for example when passed arguments are to be used for computing.

Take the following code for example

```
ctypedef np.float32_t dtype_t


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cpdef tuple sor_fx(dtype_t[:,:] A, dtype_t[:,:] mask, int max_iterations, dtype_t error, dtype_t alpha):
    cdef:
        int n "n"
        int m "m"
        int iteration "iteration"
    cdef:
        dtype_t norm "norm"
        dtype_t norm_prev "norm_prev"
        dtype_t tmp_error "tmp_error"
        dtype_t alpha_ideal "alpha_ideal"
        Py_ssize_t k "k"
    
    norm_prev = 0
    norm = 0
    iteration = 0
    
    n = A.shape[0]
    m = A.shape[1]
    
    cdef dtype_t[:,:] result_potential "result_potential"
    result_potential = A.copy()
    
    alpha_ideal = 1.976/(1+(pi/sqrt(n*m)))
    if alpha == 0:
        alpha = alpha_ideal
    
    for k in range(max_iterations):
        norm = np.linalg.norm(result_potential)
        
        sor2D(n, m, result_potential, mask, alpha)
        
        tmp_error = fabs(norm - norm_prev)
        norm_prev = norm
        iteration = iteration + 1
        if tmp_error < error:
            break
    return (result_potential, tmp_error, iteration)
```

Say the sor2D function exists and works.
When we annotate this, the `for` loop gives these results

```
  __pyx_t_3 = __pyx_v_max_iterations;
  __pyx_t_4 = __pyx_t_3;
  for (__pyx_t_5 = 0; __pyx_t_5 < __pyx_t_4; __pyx_t_5+=1) {
    k = __pyx_t_5;
```

So here my concerns are that the `cdef Py_ssize_t k` line get's annotated to `CYTHON_UNUSED Py_ssize_t k;` and then it gets set to `k = __pyx_t_5;` after the for loop?

I am very confused and would appreciate if somebody could shed some light on this.

I understand for example if the function creates a temp variable for max_iterations, which is passed to the function and will be used to compare a few thousand times. So you create the temp variable in the function to avoid longer lookups.

But why the 'k' variable here? I already defined it IN the function and some lines like `temp_error = fabs(norm-norm_prev)` stay exactly the same for example.

Comment: C compilers are very good at identifying and eliminating unnecessary variables. Have you tried compiling the code with optimization on and seeing what the result is?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this is because you might mess around with the variables. Let's imagine that you have the loop:

```
for k in range(max_iterations):
   max_iterations = 0
   k = 100
```

If Cython generated the code

```
for (__pyx_v_k = 0; __pyx_v_k < __pyx_v_max_iterations; ++__pyx_v_k)
```

then that loop is broken. It simply won't work the way that it would in Python. By using temporary variables Cython keeps the loop entirely under it's control.

It largely doesn't matter. As @templatetypedef says in the comments, C compilers are pretty good. They'll optimize out unused assignments and the double assignment for `max_iterations`. This level of optimisations is really simple and really obvious for them.